# Can't find element through text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I'm writing an automated test in Java where I want to send text of an element I need clicked, to be found through that text. Here's the code:

```java
public void selectElement(String elementName, String type, String input){

        By elementToSelect = By.xpath("//*[text()='" + elementName + "']");

        switch (type) {
            case "Photo", "Radio", "Button", "Checkbox" -> {
                driver.findElement(elementToSelect).click();
            }
            case "Edit" -> {
                WebElement edit = driver.findElement(elementToSelect);
                edit.sendKeys(input + org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER);
            }
         
        }
    }
```

I also tried with this but no such luck:

```java
 WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return $(\":contains('" + elementToSelect + "'):last\").get(0);");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant fragment of the html, for a [mcve].

Comment: What happens? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: It produces the following error message:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element:  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='Linearmodule']"}